# Tedious integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm new to *Mathematica* so I'm not familiar with its potential use to solve tedious symbolically integrals. I'm trying to solve the following one:

```
Integrate[(U - 4 k (Sin[y] - 2 Cos[Sqrt[3] x/2] Sin[y/2]))/
  Sqrt[(U - 4 k (Sin[y] - 2 Cos[Sqrt[3] x/2] Sin[y/2]))^2 + 
  4*t^2 (3 + 2 Cos[y] + 4 Cos[y/2] Cos[Sqrt[3] x/2])], {y, 0, 
  1/Sqrt[3] (x + 2 Pi/Sqrt[3]) + 2 Pi/3}, {x, -2 Pi/Sqrt[3], 0}, 
  Assumptions -> U -> 0]
```

But it takes a long time without outputting a solution.

I'm not sure if by writing `Integrate` is all I can do to solve this integral or if there is something else I could do.

Comment: Why not start with some simple integrals, perhaps using the help file for Integrate? Once you have solved a few simple ones, maybe you'll ee how to work the more complicated one.

Comment: "U -> 0" looks funny. Do you mean U equals zero? U is greater than or equal to zero? Is that just a typo? (just edit in a correction if you can)

Comment: sorry I thought I got the syntaxis right U->0 meant U<<1 (I swear to have seen it somewhere)

Comment: If the limits of integration limits for `y` depend on `x`, then the limits for `x` are given first.  In other words, `{x, -2 Pi/Sqrt[3], 0}` comes before `{y, 0, 
  1/Sqrt[3] (x + 2 Pi/Sqrt[3]) + 2 Pi/3}`.

Comment: I guess if there is no analytical expression for it, maybe solving perturbatively in U. How could I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems unlikely that a symbolic solution can be obtained with `Integrate`, even for `U == 0`.  So, I suggest solving the integral numerically.  For `U == 0`, the result is,

```
f[t_] := NIntegrate[(-4  (Sin[y] - 2 Cos[Sqrt[3] x/2] Sin[y/2]))/
    Sqrt[(-4  (Sin[y] - 2 Cos[Sqrt[3] x/2] Sin[y/2]))^2 + 
    4*t^2 (3 + 2 Cos[y] + 4 Cos[y/2] Cos[Sqrt[3] x/2])], {x, -2 Pi/
    Sqrt[3], 0}, {y, 0, 1/Sqrt[3] (x + 2 Pi/Sqrt[3]) + 2 Pi/3}]
ListLinePlot[Quiet@Table[f[t], {t, 0, 10, .1}], DataRange -> {0, 10},  AxesLabel -> {t, f}]
```

[image]

Results for finite `U` can be obtained in a similar manner.